# Getting the response result as an array and not a object in web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services

There is a php application which will read the result from the web service i have created. 
The xml response they want is like

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <WorkResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <WorkResult>Name<WorkResult>
        <WorkResult>Occupation<WorkResult>
      </WorkResult>
    </WorkResponse>
  </s:Body>
```

But my method return like this `

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <WorkResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <WorkResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:string>Name</a:string>
        <a:string>Occupation</a:string>
      </WorkResult>
    </WorkResponse>
  </s:Body>`
```

And below is the method I have written in the web service

```
public string[] Work()
    {
        string[] request = new String[2];
        request[0] = "Name";
        request[1] = "Occupation";
        return request;
    }
```

How can I do to get the result they want.
Please help me to come out of this issue

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: I am doing it in wcf service

Answer (score 1):

If you need `WorkResult` node to contain both ***"Name"*** and ***"Occupation"*** and at the same level in the xml, you can achieve it returning a `List` in your WebMethod `Work()`. Here is an example:

```
public List<String> Work()
{
    public List<String> result = new List<String>();
    result.Add("Name");
    result.Add("Occupation");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of your code and why it solves the issue? *Code only* answers are often not that helpful.

Comment: Thank's @Zabuza for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried with it. But the result is same



_italic_ **bold**  `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <WorkResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <WorkResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:string>Name</a:string>
        <a:string>Occupation</a:string>
      </WorkResult>
    </WorkResponse>
  </s:Body>`

Comment: I am doing it in wcf service