# Change the XML Format of the Response message in wCF

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

Related to my previous Post

[Getting the response result as an array and not a object in web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921434/getting-the-response-result-as-an-array-and-not-a-object-in-web-service?noredirect=1#comment78802753_45921434)

I have written a web service and the response message of the service is as below

```
 s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <signOnResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <signOnResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:string>NA</a:string>
        <a:string>NA</a:string>
        <a:string>NA</a:string>
        <a:string>10</a:string>
      </signOnResult>
    </signOnResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need the change the response as follow

```
  s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Header />
      <s:Body>
        <signOnResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <signOnResult>NA</signOnResult>
            <signOnResult>NA</signOnResult>
            <signOnResult>NA</signOnResult>
            <signOnResult>10</signOnResult>
        </signOnResponse>
      </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

The web method I have written returns the string array.

To get the response to my preferred structure i was doing an research whether i could change the format the XML is serialized to give the response. But i couldn't find the proper solution. I tried implementing **IClientMessageInspector** too.

Note : The client which is written in php can read the XML structure which is not under the string object. it can read only the below XML. And no changes can be done to the client code.

```
  s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <s:Header />
          <s:Body>
        <signOnResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <signOnResult>NA</signOnResult>
            <signOnResult>NA</signOnResult>
            <signOnResult>NA</signOnResult>
            <signOnResult>10</signOnResult>
        </signOnResponse>
      </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What does your response class look like?

Try this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="signOnResponse", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public class SignOnResponse {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="signOnResult", Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
    public List<string> SignOnResult { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName="xmlns")]
    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please see my previous post. so u can get a clear image. I have done it in WCF

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921434/getting-the-response-result-as-an-array-and-not-a-object-in-web-service?noredirect=1#comment78802753_45921434

Comment: Please see my previous post. so u can get a clear image. I have done it in WCF

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921434/getting-the-response-result-as-an-array-and-not-a-object-in-web-service?noredirect=1#comment78802753_45921434)